# Link an Excel sheet to a Table in MS Access - Using VBScript

Tags: excel, ms-access, vbscript, linked-tables

I am trying to create a Linked table in MS Access linked to Excel sheet. I want to do this through VBscripting.

My Scenario is I will have a excel sheet which will be updated very often. But my script picks up the values from the table in MSAccess which should be a replica of the Excel sheet (Linked table).

So I want to know if there is any code in VBscript wherein I can create a Linked table to Excel Sheet.

Comment: This sounds a little strange. If the Excel is already linked, the new values will show up. The sheet should only need to be linked once. What is the problem you are trying to overcome with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample script.

```
   Dim cn ''As ADODB.Connection
   Dim ct ''As ADOX.Catalog
   Dim tbl ''As ADOX.Table

   Dim strLinkXL ''As String
   Dim strMDB ''As String

   strLinkXL = "C:\Docs\LTD.xls"
   strMDB = "C:\Docs\LTD.mdb"

   ''Create Link...
   Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
          "Data Source=" & strMDB & ";" & _
          "Persist Security Info=False"

   Set ct = CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")
   Set ct.ActiveConnection = cn

   Set tbl = CreateObject("ADOX.Table")
   Set tbl.ParentCatalog = ct


   ''Link Excel using named range
   Set tbl = CreateObject("ADOX.Table")
   Set tbl.ParentCatalog = ct

   With tbl
     .Name = "LinkTableXLRange"
     .properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Provider String") = "Excel 8.0;DATABASE=" _
         & strLinkXL & ";HDR=Yes"
     ''The named range
     .properties("Jet OLEDB:Remote Table Name") = "Data_Range"
     .properties("Jet OLEDB:Create Link") = True
   End With

   ''Append the table to the tables collection
   ct.Tables.Append tbl
   Set tbl = Nothing

   ''Link Excel by sheet name
   Set tbl = CreateObject("ADOX.Table")
   Set tbl.ParentCatalog = ct

   With tbl
     .Name = "LinkTableXLSheet"
     .properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Provider String") = "Excel 8.0;DATABASE=" _
           & strLinkXL & ";HDR=Yes"
     ''Note the use of $, it is necessary
     .properties("Jet OLEDB:Remote Table Name") = "Sheet2$"
     .properties("Jet OLEDB:Create Link") = True
   End With

   ''Append the table to the tables collection
   ct.Tables.Append tbl
   Set tbl = Nothing
```

From: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Linking_Tables_via_Jet_and_ADO